# Pass variables to .sh script in Terraform module

Tags: terraform0.12+

I tried to pass variables to .sh script in Terraform module "matti/resource/shell" but It did not work.

In main.tf:

```
module "account_create" {
  source  = "matti/resource/shell"
  command = "/bin/bash ${path.module}/create_account.sh"
}
```

In create_account.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -X POST -H 'api-key:'"$API_KEY"'' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"account":{"name":"$ACCOUNT_NAME"}, "users":[{"email":"$EMAIL", "password":"$PASSWORD", "first_name":"$FIRST_NAME", "last_name":"$LAST_NAME", "role":"readonly", "owner":"true"}]}' https://***/accounts > /tmp/return.json
```

In variables.tf

```
variable "API_KEY" {
  description = "API Key"
  default = "***"
}
```

I have no idea why this happened in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution for this, add environment = { ... } in the module.

```
module "account_create" {
  source          = "matti/resource/shell"
  command_windows = "/bin/bash ${path.module}/create_account.sh"

  environment = {
    "ACCOUNT_NAME" : var.ACCOUNT_NAME,
    "USER_EMAIL" : var.USER_EMAIL,
    "USER_FIRST_NAME" : var.USER_FIRST_NAME,
    "USER_LAST_NAME" : var.USER_LAST_NAME
  }

  sensitive_environment = {
    "API_KEY" : var.API_KEY,
    "USER_PASSWORD" : var.USER_PASSWORD
  }
}
```